# Laravel Mix: "npm run prod" fails but "npm run watch " works fine- React

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-mix, babel-loader

I have a laravel 8 app and i'm running react on it. I have successfully built my application but now I need to compile my app for production, but it keeps failing whenever I run `npm run prod`. And I believe it has something to do with my react redux. It can't seem to handle that type of file configuration whenever I try to compile for production. Meanwhile `npm run watch` still works perfectly fine.

Here's the error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\pro-oms>npm run prod

> enlite_prime@1.4.3 prod C:\xampp\htdocs\pro-oms
> npm run production


> enlite_prime@1.4.3 production C:\xampp\htdocs\pro-oms
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade`


 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                 17:32:19

 error  in ./resources/js/components/app.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (41:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| const render = messages => {
|   ReactDOM.render(
>     <Provider store={store}>
|       <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
|         <ConnectedRouter history={history}>

 @ ./resources/js/app.js 15:0-30
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

 3 assets

ERROR in ./resources/js/components/app.js 41:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (41:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| const render = messages => {
|   ReactDOM.render(
>     <Provider store={store}>
|       <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
|         <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
 @ ./resources/js/app.js 15:0-30
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! enlite_prime@1.4.3 production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the enlite_prime@1.4.3 production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\KALU KECHUKWU EA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-21T16_32_26_115Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! enlite_prime@1.4.3 prod: `npm run production`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the enlite_prime@1.4.3 prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-21T16_32_26_214Z-debug.log
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "enlite_prime",
    "version": "1.4.3",
    "description": "React.js fullstack web template for expert and experienced fullstack developer",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "last 2 versions",
        "> 1%",
        "IE 10"
    ],
    "lint-staged": {
        "*.js": [
            "npm run lint:eslint:fix",
            "git add --force"
        ],
        "*.json": [
            "prettier --write",
            "git add --force"
        ]
    },
    "pre-commit": "lint:staged",
    "resolutions": {
        "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0"
    },
    "dllPlugin": {
        "path": "node_modules/react-boilerplate-dlls",
        "exclude": [
            "@types/googlemaps",
            "@types/markerclustererplus",
            "autosuggest-highlight",
            "chalk",
            "compression",
            "convert-source-map",
            "cross-env",
            "dotenv",
            "etag",
            "express",
            "fs",
            "ip",
            "jsdom",
            "minimist",
            "mocha",
            "moment",
            "sanitize.css",
            "serve-favicon",
            "slick-carousel",
            "tunnel-agent"
        ],
        "include": [
            "core-js",
            "lodash",
            "eventsource-polyfill"
        ]
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/polyfill": "7.4.3",
        "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.11",
        "@date-io/moment": "1.3.8",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.7.0",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
        "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.33",
        "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.8",
        "@types/googlemaps": "^3.38.1",
        "@types/markerclustererplus": "^2.1.33",
        "acorn": "^6.1.1",
        "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.1.1",
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "bourbon": "^5.1.0",
        "bourbon-neat": "^3.0.0",
        "chalk": "^2.4.1",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "compression": "1.7.4",
        "connected-react-router": "6.6.1",
        "cross-env": "5.2.0",
        "date-fns": "2.1.0",
        "detect-browser": "^3.0.0",
        "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
        "downshift": "^1.31.12",
        "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
        "draft-js-inline-toolbar-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "draft-js-plugins-editor": "^2.1.1",
        "draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.3",
        "draftjs-to-markdown": "^0.5.1",
        "express": "4.16.4",
        "firebase": "^7.24.0",
        "fontfaceobserver": "2.0.13",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "history": "4.7.2",
        "hoist-non-react-statics": "3.0.1",
        "immutable": "3.8.2",
        "intl": "1.2.5",
        "invariant": "2.2.4",
        "ip": "1.1.5",
        "jsdom": "^13.0.0",
        "jss": "^10.0.0",
        "jss-rtl": "^0.3.0",
        "keycode": "^2.2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "lru-memoize": "^1.0.2",
        "marked": "^1.2.7",
        "minimist": "1.2.0",
        "mocha": "^6.1.4",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "mui-datatables": "^2.13.1",
        "prop-types": "15.7.2",
        "rcolor": "^1.0.1",
        "react": "16.8.6",
        "react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll": "^1.0.11",
        "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.4",
        "react-calendar": "^2.17.4",
        "react-clock": "^2.3.0",
        "react-countup": "^3.0.3",
        "react-dom": "16.8.6",
        "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.12.13",
        "react-dropzone": "^10.2.1",
        "react-event-listener": "^0.6.1",
        "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
        "react-helmet": "6.0.0-beta",
        "react-intl": "2.8.0",
        "react-ionicons": "^2.1.6",
        "react-jss": "^10.0.0",
        "react-loadable": "5.5.0",
        "react-loading-bar": "0.0.7",
        "react-markdown": "^3.1.5",
        "react-modal": "^3.4.4",
        "react-number-format": "^3.3.4",
        "react-popper": "^0.10.4",
        "react-redux": "^7.0.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
        "react-scrollspy": "^3.3.5",
        "react-select": "^3.0.4",
        "react-slick": "^0.23.1",
        "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
        "react-swipeable-views": "^0.12.13",
        "react-syntax-highlighter": "^7.0.0",
        "react-text-mask": "^5.3.2",
        "recharts": "^1.4.2",
        "recompose": "^0.28.2",
        "redux": "4.0.1",
        "redux-form": "8.2.0",
        "redux-immutable": "4.0.0",
        "redux-saga": "1.0.2",
        "redux-saga-firebase": "^0.15.0",
        "reselect": "4.0.0",
        "sanitize.css": "8.0.0",
        "serve-favicon": "^2.4.5",
        "sinon": "^7.3.2",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "tunnel-agent": "^0.6.0",
        "warning": "4.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "7.4.3",
        "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.4.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "7.4.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "7.2.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.4.3",
        "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
        "@babel/register": "7.4.0",
        "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "3.1.1",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
        "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
        "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "2.2.0",
        "babel-plugin-lodash": "3.3.4",
        "babel-plugin-react-intl": "3.0.1",
        "babel-plugin-react-transform": "3.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.4.24",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "chai": "^4.2.0",
        "circular-dependency-plugin": "5.0.2",
        "compare-versions": "3.4.0",
        "compression-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0",
        "coveralls": "3.0.2",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "css-loader": "3.4.2",
        "enzyme": "3.7.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.6.0",
        "enzyme-to-json": "3.3.4",
        "eslint": "5.16.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "17.1.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "13.1.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "4.1.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.11.1",
        "eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.17.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
        "eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "1.0.0",
        "eventsource-polyfill": "0.9.6",
        "exports-loader": "0.7.0",
        "file-loader": "3.0.1",
        "happypack": "^5.0.1",
        "html-loader": "0.5.5",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
        "imports-loader": "0.8.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lint-staged": "8.1.5",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "ngrok": "3.1.1",
        "node-plop": "0.18.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "null-loader": "0.1.1",
        "offline-plugin": "5.0.6",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
        "plop": "2.3.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
        "pre-commit": "1.2.2",
        "prettier": "1.17.0",
        "prismjs": "^1.11.0",
        "raw-loader": "2.0.0",
        "react-app-polyfill": "0.2.2",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "rimraf": "2.6.3",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "sass-material-colors": "0.0.5",
        "shelljs": "^0.8.3",
        "style-loader": "0.23.1",
        "stylelint": "10.0.1",
        "stylelint-config-recommended": "2.2.0",
        "stylelint-config-styled-components": "0.1.1",
        "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "1.6.0",
        "svg-url-loader": "2.3.2",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.2.3",
        "url-loader": "1.1.2",
        "webpack": "4.30.0",
        "webpack-cli": "3.3.0",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.6.2",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.24.3 ",
        "webpack-pwa-manifest": "4.0.0",
        "whatwg-fetch": "3.0.0"
    }
}
```

Here's my `webpack.mix.js`:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */
mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        publicPath: '/pro-oms/public/'
    }
})
.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: run this command yarn upgrade

Comment: Done, but it didn't resolve my problem @IrshadKhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem by replacing my `.babelrc` file with a `babel.config.js` file.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: false,
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
  plugins: [
    'styled-components',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from'
  ]
};
```